# How can I verify button taps for widgets in Widgetbook?

Tags: flutter, widgetbook

If I am wanting to build a button widget in isolation using [widgetbook](https://docs.widgetbook.io/widgetbook/overview), how can I verify that a function will run upon button tap? I have only been able to change the parameters via the knobs functionality. I realize that I can just test the button tap outside of widgetbook, but I am hoping to have a way to verify all functionality only using widgetbook.

Comment: Not a full answer, but it is possible to verify taps by adding a debug print. The log will not appear in widget book, but it will in the terminal.